# R Applying self made formatting function over data frame R

Tags: r

I am using R and I need to format the number within a dataframe, notably by imposing the number of digits before the decimal separator as well as after. E.g. `3.56` must become `"0003,56000"`.

So I built my own function:

```
format <- function(x, nbr_before_comma, nbr_after_comma){

  x= round(x, nbr_after_comma)
  x = toString(x)
  l = strsplit(x, "[.]")[[1]]

  #print(l)

  #print(nchar(l[2]))

  before_comma = paste0(strrep("0",nbr_before_comma - nchar(l[1])),l[1])
  after_comma = ifelse(length(l) > 1,
                         paste0(l[2],strrep("0",nbr_after_comma - nchar(l[2]))),
                         strrep("0", nbre_after_comma))

  res = paste0(before_comma, ",", after_comma)

  return(res)

}
```

Trying this on a single number will work. Now I am trying to apply this to a dataframe. Let's take the toy example:

```
df <- data.frame("a" = c(2.5,3.56,4.5))
```

I define moreprecisely what I want:

```
format44 <- function(x){

  return(format(x,4,4))

}
```

I have tried several possibilities:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, format44)
```

with `dplyr`:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(a = format44(a))
```

and finally:

```
df["a"] <- lapply(df["a"],format44)
```

None will work. actually, I get the same output everytime:

```
          a
1 0002,5, 3
2 0002,5, 3
3 0002,5, 3
```

Any idea what the problem is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `mapply` suits better you:

`df$b <- mapply(format44, df$a)`

You do not even need the `format44` wrapper. You can use:

```
df$c <- mapply(format, df$a, 4,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sprintf` and then translate the decimal points to comma:

```
before <- after <- 4
fmt <- sprintf("%%0%d.%df", before + after + 1, after)
transform(df, a = chartr(".", ",", sprintf(fmt, a)))
```

giving:

```
          a
1 0002,5000
2 0003,5600
3 0004,5000
```

or writing this with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

before <- after <- 4
df %>%
  mutate(a = "%%0%d.%df" %>%
             sprintf(before + after + 1, after) %>% 
             sprintf(a) %>%
             chartr(".", ",", .))
```

giving:

```
          a
1 0002,5000
2 0003,5600
3 0004,5000
```